D3. How to scale the text so that it all fits into the drawing area
I use D3 to draw everything on the screen, the problem is that i want all the elements to fit in the block, while leaving as little free space as possible, how to do this, size can take a value from 1 to infinity. At the same time, it is necessary to preserve their ratio between themselves, how to do this is clear, but the question is how to calculate the multiplier that will allow them all to fit into the given block sizes.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-cloud/build/d3.layout.cloud.min.js"></script>

const width = 800;
const height = 600;

const svg = d3
    .select("#tagCloud")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

const layout = d3.layout.cloud()
    .size([width, height])
    .words(tags.map(tag => ({ text: tag.text, size: tag.size, url: tag.url })))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(() => ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90)
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(x => x.size)
    .on("end", draw);

layout.start();

function draw(words) {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("font-size", x => `${x.size}px`)
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", () => d3.schemeCategory10[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)])
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", x => `translate(${x.x}, ${x.y}) rotate(${x.rotate})`)
        .text(x => x.text)
        .on("click", function (item, index) {
            if (item.url) {
                window.location.href = item.url;
            }
        });
}


Do you mean to allow any size value? You could use a scale. For example, d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, d3.max(tags, d => d.size)]).range([10, 100]) will keep the size within the 10 to 100 pixel range, even if you have size 1 or 1 million. If your sizes change in a non-linear fashion, you can use a non-linear scale, or a log scale (d3.scaleLog) if you have very high and very low values.
